# Collapse line vertically so that every word is on a new line

Tags: text-processing, vim

Given a string like:

`"Hello World, how are you today?"`

Is there a way in Vim to collapse this line vertically such that every word appears on a new line, i.e.:

```
    "Hello
    World,
    how
    are
    you
    today?"
```

I had something similar in mind like executing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> which wraps lines relative to a fixed width which can be set in `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by replacing the spaces in the line with newlines.

`:%s/\s/\r/g`

This will replace on all lines(`%s`), all spaces (`\s`) with newlines (`\r`).

You can remove the percent sign to limit the replacement to the current line.

Comment: Very nice! Simple and elegant. (Be patient, I can accept your answer in five minutes. :))